# How to backup the pages of a wikilibrary from SharePoint Online with Powershell to my own drive?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I use a wikilibrary on sharepoint online. How can I backup the wikilibrary pages (which are HTML)
to my own computer using PnpPowershell or CSOM?
Greetings, P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a sample script to get all page files from a library and download to local drive for your reference:

```
#Set Parameters
$TenantSiteURL = "https://<tenant>.sharepoint.com"
$SiteRelativeURL = "/sites/<sitename>"
$LibraryName = "Wiki Page Library"
$DownloadPath ="C:\Temp\Downloads\ "
 
#Connect to PNP Online as Virtual Drive "SPO:\"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TenantSiteURL -CreateDrive -Credentials (Get-Credential)
 
#Change the Path and navigate to the source site
Set-Location -Path SPO:\$SiteRelativeURL
 
#Download Document Library to Local Drive
Copy-PnpItemProxy -Recurse -Force $LibraryName $DownloadPath
```

Reference: [SharePoint Online: PowerShell to Download All Files from a Document Library.](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-download-all-files-from-document-library-using-powershell.html)